# URL Canonicalization - Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, normalization

I am probably attempting to take URL Canonicalization a bit too far but here it goes anyway.

Basically I am looking to the following:

1. 301 redirect every base url to http://www.mydomain.com/ some pages are https it should recognize that and continue to use https where already used/requested
2. 301 redirect away any trailing slashes ie http://www.mydomain.com/page/ becomes http://www.mydomain.com/page (I already have a line of code that finds the index.php page - this site is built on Codeigniter)

   - I Don't want the base url to have the slash stripped that is the only time a slash should be left behind
3. Find any instances of index.php (in the front middle or end of the url) and 301 redirect them out

   - ie http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/page/index.php/ becomes http://www.mydomain.com/page
4. 301 redirect any use of my ip address to the actual domain

   - ie 11.11.111.111/page/index.php would become http://www.mydomain.com/page

Here is what I have so far in my htaccess file in my root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^(.*)(/index\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php/$  http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(mydomain\.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^11\.11\.111\.111$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#This makes sure that the server actually finds the index file although its not in the url
RewriteCond $1   !^(index\.php|images|assets|downloads|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /index\.php/$1 [L]
```

I am stuck right now any help would be greatly appreciated!!

### Revisions!!

I have made some progress and here is what I have so far

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [r=301,L]

# index.php to / at the base url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [r=301,L]

# force www.
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^paolienvelope.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.paolienvelope.com/$1 [r=301,L]

# force no IP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^70.40.204.154
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.paolienvelope.com/$1 [r=301,L]

#codeigniter direct
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|downloads|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This successfully forces ip to url
Removes index.php or index.html from the url but correctly directs to the index file despite
makes sure the base url has www.
Still dont have the code to remove the trailing slash from only the request
any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Which part exactly is not working?

Comment: index.php only gets removed if its in the very beginning of the url and nothing is after it...the website I am working on is paolienvelope.com

Comment: I wish I could help more but I can't see it atm.

Comment: Im sorry cant see what? the webpage is rendering currently

Comment: I meant I can't see whats going wrong. I don't know enough of htaccess yet i guess. I'll keep looking.

Comment: We had a similar issue regarding your #2 and I believe #3 as well. It drove us crazy! But here was our solution, it may be of help to you: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-to-remove-trailing-slashes-from-url-with-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

# index.php remove any index.php parts
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html)
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)(.*)$ $1$3 [R=301,L]

# force www. (also does the IP thing)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.paolienvelope\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.paolienvelope.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# remove tailing slash
DirectorySlash off
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|downloads|css|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# codeigniter direct
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|downloads|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The force www. ignores the end of the url example http://paolienvelope.com/pe/faq reroutes to http://www.paolienvelope.com

Comment: Also the remove trailing slash adds the file directory to the url on every request..

Comment: And when index.php is positioned http://www.paolienvelope.com/index.php the url redirects to the root directory again leading to a 404 error

Comment: My bad on the www. part. Fixed it above. The directory problem might have something to do with DirectorySlash. Turn it off with the above code. The index.php problem is understandable. `/` rewrites to `/index.php/` which redirects to `/index.php`. Should be fixed with edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to solve this one point at the time. As said I'm no pro at this yet but any bit helps i guess:

I'll start with **2.** because that one seems easier:

```
#get rid of trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Does this work, instead of what you have?

source:
http://blog.valtersboze.com/2009/06/add-or-remove-trailing-slash-in-url-with-htaccess/